# Is Tokina "Exchangeable" lens compatible with both Nikon & Canon DSLRs?

Tags: lens, dslr, tokina

Can someone please explain if [the following Tokina "Exchangeable" lens (Tokina 14-20mm F2)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/d/B019SLL820/) would be compatible with my Nikon D500?

If yes, will it perform as if it was a dedicated Nikon mount?

I am assuming Exchangeable is same thing as Interchangeable or are both different??

In description it only says following:

TOKINA Lens AT-X 14-20mm F2 Pro DX - C/EF

Does "C/EF" in above line means it's for Canon/EF? and it won't work on Nikon?

Comment: Did you click on the "Enter your model number" link (right below "5 new from £473.64") on that Amazon page? It opens the Amazon Partfinder, asking you to enter your camera brand (Nikon) and model (D500). When I did that, it said "We're not sure this item fits your 
NIKON D500".

Comment: In my side, when I scroll to description (following the link) I can read: `A fast wide-angle zoom for Canon EF mount APS-C-format DSLRs` then it looks to be for Canon. At least I think amazon have a good return policy and you should be able to return the item in case it does not fit. The fact they put many advert and suggestions around hides a bit the real content of the current showed item (general remark for amazon).

Answer (score 7):

Tokina does not, actually, label or market this as an "Exchangeable" lens. This is **something wonky with Amazon's data entry**, and makes me suspicious of the listing as a whole. See the [actual official page for this lens at Tokina's own web site](http://www.tokinalens.com/product/at_x_14_20_f2_pro_dx/), which has *no such language*. Instead, it says:

> The lens is designed for use with either Canon or Nikon DSLR cameras with APS-C sensors.

Note also that the Amazon listing you've linked to says "User Manual Included [Cannot Guarantee this will be in English]". This is internet code for "OMG RUN AWAY FROM THIS TOO GOOD TO BE TRUE OFFER", because the next step from that is *cannot guarantee that there is anything like a warranty in your country*. Even though this particular listing appears to be sold and shipped by Amazon UK directly, something is pretty dodgy with how it got there. I'd stay away.

All that said, **this particular listing appears to be for the Canon-mount version**. The "C" at the end of the model number is a clue, and you can confirm this by using the "Enter your model number" link, where you will find that it doesn't match Nikon models and does match ones from Canon.

Comment: I totally disagree with you here Matt. This is not a "vendor"; this lens is "Dispatched from and sold by Amazon". There is no need for scaremongering. Seeing the words "Cannot Guarantee this will be in English" is not a red flag. It shouldn't be ignored of course, but it doesn't mean that this product should be blankly disregarded.

Comment: @osullic Okay, changed the wording — although I _do_ think this is suspicious, and I think "cannot guarantee this will be in English" _absolutely_ is a red flag.

Comment: @osullic I generally agree with mattdm. A lens sold not in the native country language is likely a gray market product and may not have the manufacturer's warrantee.

Comment: Completely agree with @mattdm here, that manual comment is a massive red flag. If someone chooses to go ahead anyway that's their choice but they should be aware of and balance the risk (no or limited warranty and support) vs the reward (I would want a very substantial discount before I'd even go near it)

Answer (score 4):

That Tokina lens is offered in **either** the Canon EF mount or Nikon F mount, and will fit Nikon DX cameras - of which your D500 is one.

The lens mounts are not swappable - as in, a Canon EF mount lens will not fit a Nikon F mount, and vice-versa.

This is why, when buying a 3rd party lens (Tokina, Sigma, Tamron, etc.) each of these brands makes the same lens with either a Nikon or Canon mount (or Pentax, etc.)

You will need to make sure, when buying on Amazon, eBay, Keh, etc. that you are buying a lens with a Nikon mount. They are not interchangeable.

etc.

Comment: Thanks Very much for your swift reply, much appreciated.